# Shore pass connecting flight from terminal 2 to terminal 1 at Narita

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, japan, nrt

How and where can I obtain a shore pass when I arrive at Narita terminal 2?

I asked PR airline; they said I need to claim my luggage at arrival in Narita Tokyo terminal 2. If I claim my luggage, I need to pass at immigration and clear at customs, then transfer to another terminal and another airline. If I transfer from terminal 2 to terminal 1 and I need to claim my luggage, do I need to get shore pass first? How and where do I obtain that?

Answer (score 1):

I would get a transit visa instead, assuming your nationality is one that requires a visa to enter Japan.

Timatic, the database airlines use to check travel document requirements, says that "holders of onward tickets transiting to a third country can obtain a Shore Pass on arrival for a max. stay of 72 hours only **if there are no connecting flights on the same calendar day**" (and some other requirements). It sounds like your flight is on the same day.

Relying on a shore pass requires convincing the airline to let you board, even though their system will say that a visa is required for such a connection. I would get a Japanese visa for this trip.